# Removing PouchDB documents from clients without clearing browser

Tags: pouchdb

Our dev team has recently made changes to our couch/pouchdb, which now involves moving some of the information in our webapp that was stored in the pouchdb to a SQL db instance.
It was getting a little heavy on the local db with mobile devices hence the change.

I have been informed that the only way forward now due to the tombstones that are stored in the pouchdb, is that we need to contact EVERY client and ask them to clear out web data or cache on any device they have ever used our software on. I have been informed that we must do this before we can migrate our venues to the new SQL db because it will continue to resync the tombstones if this is not done?

We are talking over 2000 venues that currently use our software.

Surely this can be done by filtering replication, deleting or removing?
I know you can only purge with couch, but there has to be an easier way than this no?

Answer (score 0):

The official approach to this is to recreate the PouchDB database, and destroy the old one.  This is discussed [here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/compact-and-destroy.html). This will allow you to eliminate the tombstones.  It may take a while, depending on the size of your local databases.

Another option, though officially discouraged, might be to use a purge plugin. You may have to write this yourself. Although I found one or two on Google, they look to be of dubious quality (thus I am not linking to them myself).

Also for reference, there is progress on adding this feature to PouchDB proper. You can track that [here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802).

Comment: thanks so much for the response and for the link, yes I had read that link also but I thought maybe I was missing something since my dev team seems so sure that the only solution was to have staff clearing out pouchdb on client machines in like 8 states and 2 countries

Comment: Your dev team is mistaken. :)